# Firebase/Crashlytics Version 4.0.0-beta.1 - ForceCrash?

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

How do you force a crash on the new version of `Firebase Crashlytics 4.0.0-beta.1`?

I have tried to crash the app with `fatalError()`, but the Crashlytics doesn't record the crash in Dashboard.

Also tried to unplug my device, run the app and force crash with `fatalError()` but still no report in Dashboard.

Also tried `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`, but getting error message `Type 'Crashlytics' has no member 'sharedInstance()'`.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash) says, use

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

Crash reports are sent to the server when you start the app again.

**Option2:** If nothing works, just declare an optional and force unwrap it. :) ***CRASH***

```
var v : Int!

// then in your viewDidLoad() or in button action
let a = v!
```

Comment: Type 'Crashlytics' has no member 'sharedInstance'

Comment: Maybe they have made some changes in beta version. Try `Crashlytics.shared.crash()` and let me know if it works

Comment: Type 'Crashlytics' has no member 'shared'

Comment: @Catalin they might have made some changes in beta. use Option2. updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fatalError()` instead of `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`

Answer (score 1):

For new SDK

```
import FirebaseCrashlytics


fatalError()
```

Comment: I have written same but I haven't seen a crash in crashlytics dashboard. Can you tell me why this happened to me.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation#test_it_out    in this url  There is trick... Look at "Test it out" section with five rule section

Comment: I have followed those five rules and i found Upload missing required dSYMs error. I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047863/12119646) but still the same.

Comment: Upload missing dysm means that Firebase Crashlytic work perfect and your crash report there  but you need to upload missing dysm  .. Firstly open terminal go to your project pod file and then go to FirebaseCrashlytics folder there is "upload-symbols"  drag drop to terminal. Then go to  where is located "GoogleService-Info.plist" again darg and drop then go to dsym  again darg and drop  as a result use this command /path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
Note that you shhould upload dsym uid with given crash

Comment: here is a link https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports  .. If your dsym is release you can download from app store

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into your Info.plist, rename the following key and set it TRUE

```
firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled -> FirebaseCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled
```

Or you can also try this

```
Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after trying everything else out there—for some reason, I didn't have the `FirebaseCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled` key in my plist at all.  I added Crashlytics some time after I'd started using Firebase; not sure if that had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use pod version in your file `pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'` .

This code is working in my case.

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase (Google) recommends to use just

```
// Force a test crash
fatalError()
```

Old API was deprecated and there is no more crash() method or throwException()

Check this
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk