# upload dSYMs to Firebase using upload-symbols

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

Trying and failing to upload dSYMS file to Firebase ever since they took away the simple and straight forward way of doing it.

I entered this into the terminal:
/Users/michael****/Desktop/Revibe/revibe-ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/michael****/Desktop/Revibe/revibe-ios/Revibe/Production-GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/michael****/Desktop/appDsyms

I get this error:
-bash: /Users/michael*****/Desktop/Revibe/revibe-ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols: No such file or directory

Firebase was saying to update my Crashlytics to 4.0.0 or higher but when I update the cocoapod, it only goes up to version 1.9.1. Similarly it says to update Fabric to 1.10.0 or higher but the highest I can get mine to go is 1.9.1.

How do I fix my this error so I can read crash reports again?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would suggest to refer answers in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821249/ios-and-firebasecrashlytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp
```

not

```
/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp
```

**Note :**

If you have upgraded to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK (version 4.0.0 or higher), locate the tool in the “FirebaseCrashlytics” folder where you installed the SDK. For CocoaPods, this will be in “Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics”.

Otherwise to make sure you have our new uploader tool, please upgrade your Fabric SDK to version 1.10.0 or higher. Locate the tool in the “Pods/Fabric” folder of your Xcode project directory, or the Fabric.framework if you installed via zip download.

Comment: That appears to have done it. I could have sworn I copied it from the documentation. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @michaeldebo, I'm trying to go the Crashlytics route. Curiously I get the error, "-bash: upload-symbols: command not found" – I'm in the right directory and I can see the binary. Any idea why this wouldn't exciting?

Comment: I get error: "error: missing required flag a/api-key", but If I insert the api Key present in GoogleService_info.plist return: "error: API key (<xxxxxx>) may only contain characters in [a-f] and [0-9], and must be 40 characters long."

Comment: @Jonah if you are running it from the FirebaseCrashlytics directory. then change 
upload-symbol to ./upload-symbol to run it successfully

Comment: I am using without pods, anyone here can help me

Comment: It uploads successfully but doesn't reflect the dSYM's in the web UI

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_9

Answer (score 12):

> Note: The Fabric SDK is now deprecated and will continue reporting
> your app's crashes until November 15, 2020. On this date, the Fabric
> SDK and old versions of the Firebase Crashlytics SDK will stop sending
> crashes for your app. To continue getting crash reports in the
> Firebase console, make sure you upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics
> SDK versions 4.0.0+ for iOS and 6.15.0+ for Unity.

**Summary**

1. Copy your pod FirebaseCrashlytics path(1.path)
2. Copy your GoogleService-Info.plist path(2.path)
3. Find dsYMs folder in your xcode project(You can find detail info below)
4. copy dsYMs the file path(3.path)

***<1.path>***/upload-symbols -gsp ***<2.path>***/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ***<3.path>***/dSYMs

***/Users/Mobile/IOS/FireApp/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics***/upload-symbols -gsp ***/Users/Mobile/IOS/FireApp/Firebase/Production***/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ***/Users/Desktop/dSYMs***

5. Run it in terminal

[image: illustration of above paths]

---

**Describe Step by step**

After using FirebaseCrashlytics instead of Fabric Crashlytics, we met an issue from firebaseConsole "Upload missing required dSYMs".

To solve this issue, you should use console/terminal prompt.

Please find below path to complete command clearly.

1. find upload-symbols command line tool path. This command line tool inside your firebaseSDK file. if you use Pods, go to pods directory.
   [image]
2. find GoogleService-Info.plist path.(this file added before your project root when installing firebase SDK) . To Find search on your xode project
   [image]
3. find dSYM_directory -name "*.dSYM"(Xcode-> Window -> Orginizer -> Archive ->(Right Click On appropriate archive file -> Show in Finder -> Show Packege Content)
   [image]

> (1.path)/upload-symbols -gsp (2.path)/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios (3.path)/dSYMs

look at the below

> /path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs

Command is ready. Please run on your terminal.
[image]

Comment: Seeing the result of the upload: It seems that you forgot the single quotes around the archive folder.

Comment: You are right. We should add "\ " before the empty.

Comment: Should I do this every time I create a new archive (build)?

Comment: @DanielZanchi if your dysm file not sending to firebase, yes you should everytime.

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy your pod FirebaseCrashlytics path
2. Copy your GoogleService-Info.plist path
3. Goto organizer select current build select show in finder, right-click show package content and copy the dsYMs folder and paste it in your desktop.
4. Zip the dsYMs folder and copy the file path.
5. Run it in terminal

Example

<---FirebaseCrashlytics path--->/upload-symbols -gsp <---GoogleService-Info.plist path----> -p ios <---dSYMs.zip path--->