# Could not complete submission of dSYM, File no longer exists at (null)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I have migrated Fabric to Firebase/Crashlytics and I am getting this below build error for my run script in an iOS project,

**Build Phase - Run Script**

```
# Name of the resource we're selectively copying
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_LOCATION=${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/App/Scripts/GoogleService-Info.plist

# Upload sysmbol
echo "Uploading dsym file"

"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_LOCATION} -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

**Build Error**

> [31merror: Could not complete submission of dSYM at /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cmkidnrcwbunsqezgsrutqkmnivn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Project/BuildProductsPath/ReleaseOfficial-iphoneos/Project.app.dSYM: Error Domain=com.crashlytics.mac.error-domain.process-dsym Code=2 "File no longer exists at (null)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=File no longer exists at (null)}

Suggested in [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61749364/1084174) didn't work for me.

**How to resolve it?**

Comment: The file destination being pointed to seems to be off. Could you double check that path and make sure that's the correct place to point to for your dSYM uploads?

Comment: @OlegKodysh I double checked and the file exists in the location.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RajD No. I skipped auto upload that time.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recently got a new Mac and faced the same issue.

After trying lot of different things with no success, I found what was wrong. All I had to do, is to move my upload DSYM script at the bottom of the build phases script list.

We talk about this script:

```html
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/YourPathToYourGoogleServiceFile/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

It has to be the last one executed

If this does not work, try this :

1. Comment your DSYM script, then archive your app.
2. Your archive should complete with success
3. Uncomment your DSYM script, and place it to the bottom list. (see correct order below)
4. Build a new archive.

**Correct order :**

1. run firebaseCrashlytics script.
2. run [CP] Embed pods frameworks
3. run DSYM Script

*NB: In some cases, having a path containing some white spaces such as 'Supporting files' may lead to unexpected behaviour.*

Comment: Last stuff if just did before : 
1. Comment your DSYM script, then archive your app.
2. Your archive should complete with success
3. Uncomment your DSYM script, place it to the bottom list.
Correct order : 3a. run firebaseCrashlytics script. 3b. run [CP] Embed pods frameworks 3c. run DSYM Script
4. Build a new archive.

Comment: You save my day Maite.

Comment: I have followed these steps still getting the same issue...

Comment: My Second archive hangs on "Run custom shell script 'DYSM script'", and is not going forward.

Comment: And the archive fails at the end

Comment: @RajD maybe you should comment your script (by adding a # before each line. Then build your archive. It the problem, gone, your script is the issue. You have to figure it out why it doesn't run. As a quick work-around, you can send your app to the store without the DSYM's and send it manually.

Comment: @RajD another thing you may take care, is to avoid placing your .plist file (the one you refers in your DSYM script) in a folder containing some spacing. This could cause issue in your script.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I've submitted app without the script for now. I'll check the plist folder thing too.

Comment: @DDelforge Yes I have space in my project name and in its folder name which contains the plist file. Maybe this could be the problem

Comment: @RajD The I would suggest you to any spaces, in folder name or file name. I should fix your issue.

Comment: correct order of scripts work for me ...
1. run
2. pod 
3. dSYM

Comment: It happens when do `pod deintegrate` then `pod install`. It will happen miscorrect order. Change it will solve the problem.