# Firebase Crashlytics crash report missing line code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I'm not sure what's the cause, I uploaded all the dSYM I could found but I still have this issue

The crash report only tells me the crash happened in function but not the line where it happened. It reports the crash as compiler-generated

In the dSYM tab it says that I'm missing 1 optional dSYM but I don't have it in my system and didn't find it in the archive of the app, also the same file is missing in the staging crash reports but I don't have any issues there so I guess it must be something else.
Did anyone run in a similar issue?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821249/ios-and-firebasecrashlytics/61749364#61749364

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.